How do I select first item in nav list of hover underline list items effects to stay underlined?
I want the first item in a list in my navigation to stay underlined, and the rest to underline on hover, with the first item only not underlining until I hover on another list item. I have already tried the first child selector to try ad it but it does not seem to work.


.nav__links a {
  padding-block: 5px;
  color: var(--text-dark);
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}

.nav__links a:hover {
  border-color: var(--btn-primary-color);
}
<ul class="nav__links" id="nav-links">
  <li><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="#company">COMPANY</a></li>
  <li><a href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
  <li class="nav__links__btn nav__remove__btn">
    <button class="btn">CONTACT US</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav__links__btn nav__remove__btn">
    <button class="btn">GET A FREE QUOTE</button>
  </li>
</ul>



I have already tried the child selector on the first li item but had no luck. I'm a bit unsure of how to approach it.
.nav__links a {
        padding-block: 5px;
        color: var(--text-dark);
        border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
    }

    .nav__links a:hover {
        border-color: var(--btn-primary-color);
    }


To clarify, the link for "HOME" should always remain underlined? Or should it only be underlined when the parent <ul> is hovered?

Yes thew 'home' should always be underlined unless hovering on the next item in the list

@Callum, so if I hover over "COMPANY" or "SERVICES" the underline on "HOME" should disappear?

Hi @DavidThomas Exaclty that.

As below.
The first child and any hovered item gets the border.
If the first child has any sibling that is hovered, its border is removed.


ul {
  list-style:none;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  background: lightblue;
  margin-right: .25em;
  padding: .25em;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  transition: border-color .2s ease;
}

a {
 text-decoration:none;
  display: block;
}

li:first-child, 
li:hover {
  border-bottom: 5px solid blue;
}

li:first-child:has( ~ li:hover) {
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
<ul>
  <li><a href="">List Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">List Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">List Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="">List Item 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="">List Item 5</a></li>
</ul>



